# How to make a superscript number outside the hyperlink box?

Tags: hyperref, superscripts, hyperlink

This is a minimal working example (in XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage{circledsteps, hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This is \hyperlink{1}{the first link}.

\lipsum[1] 

This is the second link:\hyperlink{2}{$$1+1=2.$$}

\lipsum[2] 

\begin{itemize}
\item[\Circled{1}] This is \hypertarget{1}{the first target}.
\item[\Circled{2}] This is \hypertarget{2}{the second target}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In fact, the links are texts that need more explanations and the targets are the related explanations. If there are many links, and if the links are not clickable, for example, printed on A4 papers, then the numbers will necessary for people to know the corresponding explanation of each link.

I want to put a circled number superscript next to the link box. The numbers may be set automatically but I prefer to set them manually. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\textsuperscript{\Circled{1}}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for you comment. Indeed this does the trick, but please see the edited second link. How to add a superscript in that situation? That is a situation that I was dealing with.

Comment: do you really want to put a link around a full display equation? and add a superscript?  imho that looks odd. Use the amsmath environments and put your number in the label of the equation with \tag.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. Your advice is helpful.